# Transformer, changing filename after ingestion in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I am completely new to Spring Integration package and found different advice on how to approach the problem. So far I only found one that worked, but I am unsure if it is correct or why it produces a logged Error (even though the file is ingested and re-named as I intended).

The use case for this is that my system expects a "temp_" prefix to ignore a partially downloaded file. I found that even though the default ".writing" can be changed, it only works as a suffix.

Here is the config I used:

```
SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec integrationFlow = Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory)
        .filter(chainFilter)
        .localFilename(temp_::concat)
        .remoteDirectory(remoteDirectory)
        .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
        .preserveTimestamp(true)
        .localDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(integrationFlow, pc -> pc.poller(pm -> pm.cron(cron).maxMessagesPerPoll(1).errorHandler(new SftpUtils.SftpErrorHandler())))
        .transform((File f) -> f.getName().contains(temp_) ?
                f.renameTo(new File(f.getParent(), f.getName().replace(temp_, ""))) :
                null)
        .handle((transformResult, messageHeaders) -> {
            log.info("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ({}): {}", localDirectory, transformResult);
            return null;
        })
        .get();
```

And the error being produced:

```
SftpErrorHandler: Error occured in SFTP ingestion flow, exception: nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'leapInboundFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=src\main\resources\input\genericfile.name, headers={file_originalFile=src\main\resources\input\genericfile.name, id=293a3e85-cd62-37f7-b701-bbacbf27a83f, file_name=genericfile.name, file_relativePath=genericfile.name, timestamp=1668518160014}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    .transform((File f) -> f.getName().contains(temp_) ?
            f.renameTo(new File(f.getParent(), f.getName().replace(temp_, ""))) :
            null)
```

The `transformer` is a request-reply endpoint which does not tolerate `null` as a reply.

Your logic over here is not fully clear.
Let's forget that you cannot return `null`! It's definitely wrong and has to be fixed this or other way.

What exactly do you want to return from this transformer? Probably your wish is just to rename the file and go ahead downstream with that renamed file already?

Probably you wanted something like this:

```
    .transform((File f) -> 
         { 
            if (f.getName().contains(temp_)) {
                f.renameTo(new File(f.getParent(), f.getName().replace(temp_, "")));
            }
            return f;
          })
```

?

Sorry, it is not clear what is a business task from a content of your quesiton, but I hope I explained why your error appears.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that I needed to return something from the transformer, I used the right-hand side operation thinking it would simply "do nothing". While I am, could you tell me if the 'return null' is normal in the handle() method? I took it from an example but I don't understand what should be returned in handle

Comment: Right, `null` in the `handle()` is OK. Although you might thing about `handle(MessageHandler)` instead which is indeed a one-way by its contract definition. Another operator for you is `log()`, which is, essentially, what you do in that `handle()` at the moment.